# Get response <style> tag and append it to head HTML section with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I know this is bad practice at all, but is the best solution for this case.
I have response from the server, something like this:

```
<style id="styles">.color_txt{color:green;}</style>
```

And I am trying to append in in the `head` tag:

```
 let styleEl = new DOMParser().parseFromString(res.data.html, "text/xml");
 styleEl.type= "text/css";
 // Remove current style
 document.getElementById('styles').remove();
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleEl.documentElement);
```

I see that new style is appended to the head tag, but
the problem is that the style is not applied, but removed from the elements.
I am using `React`.

//EDIT

If I manually add style via web console in the new created style tag, it doesn't apply, too.

Comment: Does it have to be in the `<head>` tag? Style tags are global, so you can put them anywhere in the document.

Comment: If the styles are in the dom, then you have a different problem. Check that the CSS rules matches your elements... make sure `color_txt` class is the correct class...

Comment: Yes,I am using same method which outputs same style, when the page first loads and then styles works, but I need to reload the page.

Comment: sounds like the selectors for the rules in the style tag aren't specific enough to override existing rules. Inspect the element(s) in dev tools elements inspector to see exactly what rules apply and in what order

Comment: Hi, they override and they are correct for the elements, because same style tag with same style loads at the beginning and it works. The only difference is a color value. After the Ajax request, I see that new color value is in the style tag with same selector, but the style doesn't apply to the element.

Answer (score 1):

There's a library to do this here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-style-tag

Here's how you could use it:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
import { Style } from "react-style-tag";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { styleTag: false };
     fetchStyleTag().then(styleTag => {
        this.setState({ styleTag });
     });
  }
  render() {
    const { styleTag } = this.state;
    return styleTag && <Style>{ styleTag }</Style>;
  }
}
```